# Distance between point and a plane represented with $3$ points in $3D$ space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have to find a distance between a plane represented with a triangle and a point in $3D$ space. I searched other questions but the plane is usually represented by a plane equation or a normal, so I am having trouble finding this distance when the plane is represented by three points.

Comment: So...do you know how to find an equation for the plane, or the normal vector, given three points in the plane?  It seems like that's all you need to do to connect these dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the cross product, obtains **a** normal vector $n =(a,b,c)$ and then Write the equation of the plan in form 
$$(\Bbb P):ax+by+cz+d =0$$

Then

$$d((x_0,y_0,z_0), \Bbb P) =\frac{|ax_0+by_0+ cz_0+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

Comment: Specifically, $d=-n\cdot p$, where $v$ is any of the vertices of the triangle, so the numerator can be written as $|n\cdot(p-v)|$, with $p$ the point being measured.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

You can find the normal vector by **cross product** and then apply the formula for the distance between plane and point.

Answer (score 1):

You've implied that it would help to have a normal. Given three points forming a triangle, we can find two nonparallel vectors in the plane. Then their cross product would be a normal to the plane because it would be orthogonal to both vectors.